# is it possible to select all elements with css3 , even if they have special style

Tags: css

I want select all elements on my `html` page and for that i tried selecting elements using `*` but this way elements with specific style , like those who selected with their class not becomes selected .   i want know is there any other selector with highest priority than `*` ?

Comment: The problem is not that the elements are not selected, the problem is that styles for other rules with higher proirity overrides the styles that you are trying to set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To override every other style inside the Style Sheet, you can use `!IMPORTANT` like this.

```
* {
  style: value !IMPORTANT;
  /* example */
  width: 100px !IMPORTANT;
}
```

This style would be applied to the element, regardless of classNames and styles it has.

Comment: oh thanks, that works. can you please tell me which browsers support this ? and can i exclude only specific classes in it ?

Comment: I don't think you can exclude only some classes and It would work on all classes! :)